# How to ignore the Null values in Insert query in access

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013

I have the  Database table where the Table needs to be updated using a form.
However all the fields in the Form need not be mandatory to be filled.
I am Writing the Below VB code for inserting However I get an error stating that there is a syntax error in the statement.As i understand it is because of the Null  Values in the Variable. I understand that I need to use DBNull.Value for all the  null Values.
Here the Thing is there are too many fields to check if the value is null or not.
any body suggest if there is a way to do a mass check on the values entered to be null?

VBCode:

```
Dim StrSQL As String
Dim StrSQL1 As String
Dim tktID As Variant
Dim Assi As Variant
Dim reopened As Variant
Dim valid As Variant
Dim Reopenreason As Variant
Dim ReassignmentAG As Variant
Dim RBSCollab As Variant
Dim SMEconf As Variant
Dim Cloabag As Variant
Dim smeName As Variant
Dim Updat  As Variant
Dim Closed As Variant
Dim iss As Variant
Dim ana As Variant
Dim res As Variant
Dim rVariant As Variant

' Assigining values

tktID = Ticket_number.Value
reopened = Ticket_Reopened.Value
valid = Valid_Reopen.Value
Assi = Assiginee.Value
Reopenreason = Reopen_reason.Value
ReassignmentAG = Reassignment_AG.Value
RBSCollab = RBS_Collab.Value
SMEconf = CkBxSMEConfirmation.Value
Cloabag = Collabarated_AG.Value
smeName = SME_Name.Value
Updat = Update.Value
Closed = Issue_Closed.Value
iss = Issue.Value
ana = Analysis.Value
res = Resolution.Value
rdate = Resolve_date.Value

'Insert values into the tables

StrSQL = "INSERT INTO Updates (TicketID,Assiginee,ReassignmentAG,RBSCollab,CollabAG,SMEconfirmation,SMEName,Update,IssueClosed,Issue,Analysis,Resolution,ResolveDate,TicketReopened,ValidReopen,ReopenReason) VALUES ('" & tktID & "','" & Assi & "','" & ReassignmentAG & "','" & RBSCollab & "','" & Cloabag & "','" & SMEconf & "','" & smeName & "','" & Updat & "','" & Closed & "','" & iss & "','" & ana & "','" & res & "','" & rdate & "','" & reopened & "','" & valid & "','" & Reopenreason & "' ) "
DoCmd.RunSQL StrSQL
```

thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Better learn to use parameters to avoid sql injection and formatting issues.

Comment: I have a lot of fields as you can.I do not thing using parameters will help

Comment: You misunderstand the reason why you would use parameters.  Consider what would happen with a `Reopenreason` of `foo'); DROP TABLE Updates; --` .

Comment: It will help.  It will improve your code.  It will prevent mishaps.  It will make you a better programmer.

Comment: Could you please provide me some Links that will help me understand this ?

Comment: @shravya [this should help](https://www.explainxkcd.com/wiki/index.php/327:_Exploits_of_a_Mom)

Comment: Or you might simply use a bound form *shrug*. It needs no code at all and knows how to deal with NULL values - both for required fields (throw an error) and non-required fields (leave them empty).

Comment: @Comintern if that were to happen OP would get the error "Characters found after end of SQL Statement" and nothing would be executed. Access protects against that kind of SQL Injection. Sure no record was inserted but also no table was dropped either.

Comment: @Brad. Interesting, I guess I'd need to mess with it in other subtly broken ways or just make it crash. Just because Access only allows one statement through that interface certainly doesn't excuse getting in the habit of building SQL commands like that.

Comment: @Comintern oh you are most certainly right. both ADO and DAO easily support parameters. That's the way to go if you are needing to write queries on code for sure.

Answer (score 2):

I, too, setup my first Access database using lots of unbound controls and SQL statements for moving data around. But this is not the way to use Access. You should be using bound forms where the controls automatically know what the constraints are based on the table/columns they are bound to.

This means much less code for you to write (and maintain), future developers can look at your Access app and know what's going on because it will be done in the Access paradigm, and if you place as much logic into your tables/relationships as possible then if someone comes along and links to your ACCDB or opens the backend they *could* enter data without entering bad data.

So ultimately this is an XY problem. Get rid of all this code (especially `DoCmd.RunSQL`) and create a bound form. Put your validation logic in foreign keys, validation rules, and/or data macros in the table.

Comment: I am using a bound form it self and have no problem adding the details in the table to which it is mapped however when a value in that form is Checked I want those details to be inserted in another table as well

Comment: @shravya I see, in that case look into making a query to insert these values. The kind that prompts you to enter things when you run it. Then use that query via the `CurrentDb`QueryDefs` collection to do the insert. the returned `QueryDef` object has a `Parameters` collection. You can add your nulls to that/unsanitized inputs to that. If I get some time I can update/write another answer.

Comment: Alternatively you could use a subform with some clever binding.

Comment: Thanks Will Try that also will be waiting to see if i can get another way to resolve this

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution to this problem could be just check for element's value before using in the inset query and if element's value is undefined than set with null.
Pass this value to database in the query.

Comment: As you can see that is my question How do i do the mass check for this?

Answer (score 0):

Do this for each field:

```
tktID = IIF(ISNULL(Ticket_number.Value),"Null","'" & Ticket_number.Value & "'")
```

Then instead of this:

```
VALUES ('" & tktID & "',...
```

Do this

```
VALUES (" & tktID & ",...
```

Or if you don't mind replacing nulls with empty strings:

```
tktID = Nz(Ticket_number.Value)
```

will do it.

Of course you should at least make sure no single quotes are in the stings, so even better:

```
 tktID = IIF(ISNULL(Ticket_number.Value),"Null","'" & Replace(Ticket_number.Value,"'","''") & "'")
```

Answer (score 0):

After building the string  for INSERT statment

```
strSql = "INSERT INTO tblmovimentiServizi ( msid, " _
& " msData, msIdDestinazione, msOraInizioServizio,  msOraFineServizio, msAndataRitorno, " _
& " msOraVincoloEntrata, msOraVincoloUscita, msidAnagraficaAutomezzi, msServizioEseguito, msNoteCommenti) " _
& " VALUES ('" & rst!newid & "', #" & rst!msData + Me.g1 & "#, '" _
& rst!msIdDestinazione & "', #" _
& rst!msOraInizioServizio & "#, #" _
& rst!msOraFineServizio & "#, '" _
& rst!msAndataRitorno & "', #" _
& rst!msOraVincoloEntrata & "#, #" _
& rst!msOraVincoloUscita & "#, '" _
& rst!msidAnagraficaAutomezzi & "', " _
& eseguito & ", '" _
& rst!msNoteCommenti & "'" _
& ");"
```

I added

```
strSql = Replace(strSql, "''", "null")
strSql = Replace(strSql, "##", "null")
```

and it works.